# "Fine line between" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, modismos

How do I say in Spanish "there's a fine line between" something and something else?

As in "the difference is not clear-cut" or "it's not black & white".

It feels that something like "no hay mucha diferencia entre" doesn't capture the English idiom very well.

Comment: "Una delgada línea" is frequently used  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RvBmx.jpg

Comment: @belisarius, thanks! That seems like a valid answer, you should post it as one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hay una sutil diferencia entre *X* y *Y*.

for "the difference is not clear-cut". And indeed,

> No hay mucha diferencia entre *X* y *Y*.

would be wrong. You'd be saying that the difference is negligible.

Comment: Yes, "sutil diferencia" indeed seems idiomatic. For instance, as Jorge Luis Borges [wrote](http://elprincipito.blogia.com/2005/101102-jorge-luis-borges-aprendiendo.php): *Después de un tiempo, uno aprende la sutil diferencia entre sostener una mano y encadenar un alma*

Comment: I don't quite agree. "Hay una sutil differencia" emphasizes the difference, "there's a fine line" emphasizes the proximity.

Comment: "... would be wrong. You'd be saying that the difference is negligible."  But that's what the "there's a fine line" idiom means! http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/there+is+a+fine+line+between

Comment: @leonbloy sutil means subtle. So it does emphasize the proximity AND the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Colombia:

> Hay una delgada línea entre X y Y.
>
> De X a Y solo hay un paso.

Answer (score 1):

> Del X a Y hay solo un paso

So *Del amor al odio hay solo un paso* will be *There is a fine line between love and hate*.

As Napolean said:

> There is only one step from the sublime to the ridiculous.

[In wikiquote is translated](http://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Napole%C3%B3n_Bonaparte) like *De lo sublime a lo ridículo no hay más que un paso*

> Del X a Y hay solo un paso

or

> Del X a Y no hay más que un paso

Both as idioms are the same, but for me the first is more used and I have heard it more often when you use two opposite words or in films.

Comment: Is *there is only one step* the same as *the difference is not clear-cut*?

Comment: I put `one step` because I think is the more appropiate translation for the idiom he is asking (maybe is too poetic). All three idiomas means there is no a clear difference between both words. Look at [wordreference's forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=26320&langid=24), or maybe we can ask on englishstackexchange. Likewise, as it was commented 'delgada linea' seems to be more used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fine line between = Hay una fina linea entre...

The difference is not clear-cut = La diferencia no es clara.

It's not black & white = No es o blanco o negro.

Answer (score 0):

- There's a fine line between/Hay una línea muy delgada entre
- The difference is not clear-cut/La diferencia es mínima
- It's not black & white/No es blanco y negro. Aque aquí yo usaría: No todo es blanco y negro/Nada es blanco y negro

Answer (score -1):

Ejemplo de "sutil diferencia".

> Después de un tiempo Uno aprende la sutil diferencia Entre sostener
>   una mano y encadenar el alma,

según el internet, lo escribió Borges.